# Does the custom 404 error page cover all error pages?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, security, administration, configuration

I'm new to SharePoint administration and have updated my custom error pages per [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2012/10/02/how-to-customize-error-page-page-not-found-and-access-denied-in-sharepoint-2010/) guide. It works just fine for the 404 page, but **should this also cover all other SharePoint error pages (like say, a database error)?**

Also, **how can I simulate an error so that I can verify the proper custom error page is displayed?** I'm attempting to close a security vulnerability identified on our SharePoint Foundation 2010 server so I need to be able to prove that whatever fix I implement is working before putting it into production.

Here are the steps from the link above for reference:

> First create three pages and place them in this path
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\
>
> Custom_Error.html
>
> Custom_NotFound.html
>
> Custom_AccessDenied.html
>
> Note: if you have multilingual site you need to place these pages in their language folder for example for Arabic
>
> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1025\
>
> Second Open SharePoint 2010 Management Shell with Farm Administrator User
>
> Now For Custom page Not Found runs the following Power Shell:
>
> `$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://test 
>   $webApp.FileNotFoundPage = “Custom_NotFound.html” 
>   $webApp.Update()`
>
> Run the following Power Shell:
>
> `$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://test
>   $webApp.UpdateMappedPage([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPCustomPage]::Error,"/_layouts/1033/Custom_Error.html") 
>   $webApp.Update()`

Edit: No one knows? I still haven't been able to find a solid answer through googling. :( Still no takers? I put a bounty on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Below given solution covers all SharePoint error pages**

> To configure `SharePoint Foundation server` or `SharePoint Server
>   2010` to point to a `custom 404 error Web page`, follow these steps.
>
> 1. Log on to the computer that is running SharePoint Server 2010 by using an account that has administrative permissions.
> 2. In Windows Explorer, locate the following folder:
>
> This is the path for `14 hive`
>
> ```
> %systemdrive% \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\LangID
> ```
>
> **Notes**
>
> In this path, `%systemdrive%` represents the actual drive name of the
>   drive on which the operating system is installed.
>
> In this path, `LangID` represents the actual language ID of the
>   language that you use. For example, 1033 is the language ID for U.S.
>   English.
>
> 3. Create the custom HTML file:
>
>    On the computer that is running SharePoint Server 2010, copy the Sps404.html file to a temporary folder.
>
>    Rename the Sps404.html file. For example, give the file the following name: `Custom404.html`
>
>    Modify the `Custom404.html` file to suit your needs for a custom 404 error message using an HTML editor.
> 4. Copy the `Custom404.html` file to the `%systemdrive% \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>      Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\LangID` folder.
> 5. Run the following PowerShell commands from the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell:
>
> **PowerShell Command**
>
> ```
> $webapp =Get-SPWebApplication http://<serverUrl>:<port>
> $webapp.FileNotFoundPage = "Custom404.html"
> $webapp.update()
> ```
>
> Verify that the property is set by running the following command:
>
> ```
> (Get-SPWebApplication http://<serverUrl>:<port>).FileNotFoundPage
> ```
>
> **Notes**
>
> • In this code,  represents the actual URL of the Web
>   application where you are setting the custom 404 error page.
>
> • In this code,  represents the nonstandard port number, if any,
>   that is assigned to the Web application.
>
> • In this code, Custom404.html represents the actual name that you
>   created for the custom HTML file.
>
> For more information about how to use PowerShell scripts against
>   SharePoint 2010, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
>
> [Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536539(office.14).aspx)
>
> **Note**
>
> By default in SharePoint Server 2010, the FileNotFoundPage property is
>   set to the "null" setting.

**To Simulate an error you can follow steps mentioned in below mentioned link. So that You can verify the proper custom error page is displaying or not**

[IIS Custom Error Page for common error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169362/iis-custom-error-page-for-common-error)

Comment: Great thanks. I'll award the bounty when it lets me.

Comment: Happy to help you... :)

Comment: I've done this. it work with web sites and documents removed. But not with site collection removed ? have you any idea to have a custom page for a site collection removed ? thanks